# How will I convert value in StringWriter into XML Format.?

Tags: c#, xml, wcf

I have written a Service and in the I need a return type as n XML which I will passing to Client. I am having Values in string writer as - `<newdataset> <table> <Slno>1</Slno></table><Name>Andrew</Name><table><Slno>2</Slno><name>Trisha</name></table></newdataset>`

What I need to return is a proper XML  format from the service to the client.

P.S. - It should have a header like all the XMLs has -- like this : <`?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>`

Thanks,

Nayan

Comment: What kind of service have you written and how does it communicate with the client? If it is WCF it will generate a WSDL which can be consumed by the clients and it will return a proper SOAP response out of the box.

Comment: Dear  Ben Robinson,     We have written Basic WCF Service. We got value in Datatable.The problem is we are not able to return the Value in the form of XML format to the client application.We are using BasicHttp Binding.

Comment: Why can't you return the value, what is stopping you, do you get an error?

Comment: We are getting the values in the tag format just like the XML Format. But the problem is we need the Header too which I have mentioned in my Question... Like - <?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>

Comment: We are using the below Code ------                                               StringWriter strwtr = new StringWriter();             dt.WriteXml(strwtr);

Comment: If all you need to do is add the header then simply concatenate it with the string. Such as `data = header + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine + data`

Comment: Hi i am getting service error because of the concatenate.is there any other option.?

Comment: this what i tried.                   string header="<?xml version=\'1.0\' standalone=\'yes\'?>"+strwtr;
            string data=header+strwtr.NewLine+strwtr.NewLine;
           // data = header + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine + data
            dt.WriteXml(data);

Comment: we getting output like this: <?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?><newdataset> <table> <Slno>1</Slno></table><Name>Andrew</Name><table><Slno>2</Slno><name>Trisha</name></table></newdataset>    is this valid xml document?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`DataTable.WriteXml(XmlWriter)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/10eb5kk0%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) overload.  Then when [creating the `XmlWriter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162620%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) you can pass in an [`XmlWriterSettings`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlwritersettings%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) with the necessary formatting options, including setting [`settings.OmitXmlDeclaration = false`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlwritersettings.omitxmldeclaration%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (which is actually the default).  Thus:

```
    public static string ToXml(this DataTable dt)
    {
        using (var textWriter = new StringWriter())
        {
            var settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
            settings.Indent = true;
            settings.IndentChars = "    ";
            // settings.OmitXmlDeclaration = false; not necessary since this is the default anyway.
            using (var xmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(textWriter, settings))
            {
                dt.WriteXml(xmlWriter);
                return textWriter.ToString();
            }
        }
    }
```

Thus gives the output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<newdataset>
    <Name>Andrew</Name>
    <table>
        <Slno>1</Slno>
    </table>
    <table>
        <Slno>2</Slno>
        <name>Trisha</name>
    </table>
</newdataset>
```

The same will work for a `DataSet` as well if you have one.  (For reasons unclear to me, the [`WriteXml(TextWriter)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k84e8sy3%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) overload omits the XML declaration.)